# Add a -m32 parameter to a Makefile command

Tags: c++, makefile

i have a simple question.

This is my Makefile

```
#############################################################################
#
#   Makefile for building the Long Range Navigator program
#
#############################################################################

PC = true
#PC = false

PWD       := $(shell pwd)

#GUMSTIX_BUILDROOT   = /home/irmabot/gumstix-buildroot
#BUILD_ARM      = $(GUMSTIX_BUILDROOT)/build_arm_nofpu
#CROSS_COMPILE      = $(BUILD_ARM)/staging_dir/bin/arm-linux-
#BUILD_ARM           = $(wildcard $(GUMSTIX_BUILDROOT)/build_arm*)
#CROSS_COMPILE       = $(patsubst %g++, %, $(wildcard $(BUILD_ARM)/staging_dir/bin/arm-linux-uclibc*-g++))
#CROSS_COMPILE = /home/irmabot/gumstix/gumstix-oe/tmp/cross/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/
CROSS_COMPILE = /home/babbage/marbotRelease/src/processors/longRangeNavigator/arm/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/
COMMON          = ../../common
SHARED          = Shared
I32 = /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.7/bits/


#ifeq ($(strip $(CROSS_COMPILE)),)
#   $(error Unable to detect C++ Cross Compiler)
#endif

vpath %.c  %.cpp $(COMMON) $(SHARED)

CPPFLAGS +=  -I . -I $(COMMON) -I $(SHARED) -I$(I32)
CFLAGS   += -Wall -I$(I32)

ifeq ($(PC), true)
CPPFLAGS += -DPC -m32 
CFLAGS   += -DPC -m32    
CC = g++
CXX = g++

OBJS = longRangeNavigator.o GALRN.o InternalMap.o MandamiFuzzyModel.o     MembershipFunctions_1D.o Utils.o ../../common/configFile/configFile.o 

else                # else
TARGET_ARCH=-Os -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -Wa,-mcpu=xscale
CC = $(CROSS_COMPILE)g++
CXX = $(CROSS_COMPILE)g++

OBJS = \
   longRangeNavigator.o         \
    GALRN.o                         \
    InternalMap.o                   \
    MandamiFuzzyModel.o         \
    MembershipFunctions_1D.o    \
    Utils.o                         \
    ../../common/configFile/configFile.o


endif               # endif 

all: longRangeNavigator

longRangeNavigator: $(OBJS)

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions longRangeNavigator

depend .depend dep:
    @echo "Creating dependencies ..."
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -M  *.cpp  > .depend

FORCE:

.PHONY: FORCE

PREPROCESS.c = $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -E -Wp,-C,-dD,-dI

%.pp : %.c  FORCE
    $(PREPROCESS.c) $< > $@

ifeq ($(strip $(filter clean, $(MAKECMDGOALS))),)
-include .depend
endif
```

My problem is that i am compiling in a amd64 machine a 32bit code. 
This is the output

```
Creating dependencies ...
g++ -Wall -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.7/bits/ -DPC -m32 -I . -I ../../common -I Shared -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.7/bits/ -DPC -m32  -M  *.cpp  > .depend
g++  -I . -I ../../common -I Shared -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.7/bits/ -DPC -m32   -c -o longRangeNavigator.o longRangeNavigator.cpp
g++  -I . -I ../../common -I Shared -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.7/bits/ -DPC -m32   -c -o GALRN.o GALRN.cpp
g++  -I . -I ../../common -I Shared -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.7/bits/ -DPC -m32   -c -o InternalMap.o InternalMap.cpp
g++  -I . -I ../../common -I Shared -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.7/bits/ -DPC -m32   -c -o MandamiFuzzyModel.o MandamiFuzzyModel.cpp
g++  -I . -I ../../common -I Shared -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.7/bits/ -DPC -m32   -c -o MembershipFunctions_1D.o MembershipFunctions_1D.cpp
g++  -I . -I ../../common -I Shared -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.7/bits/ -DPC -m32   -c -o Utils.o Utils.cpp
g++   longRangeNavigator.o GALRN.o InternalMap.o MandamiFuzzyModel.o MembershipFunctions_1D.o Utils.o ../../common/configFile/configFile.o   -o longRangeNavigator
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `_ZNSt8_Rb_treeISsSt4pairIKSsSsESt10_Select1stIS2_ESt4lessISsESaIS2_EED1Ev' changed from 75 in longRangeNavigator.o to 81 in ../../common/configFile/configFile.o
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `_ZNSt4pairIKSsSsED1Ev' changed from 63 in longRangeNavigator.o to 69 in ../../common/configFile/configFile.o
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `longRangeNavigator.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `GALRN.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `InternalMap.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `MandamiFuzzyModel.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64
```

So, clearly the problem is here. Where a i'm linking a 32bit code with a 64bit linker.

```
g++   longRangeNavigator.o GALRN.o InternalMap.o MandamiFuzzyModel.o MembershipFunctions_1D.o Utils.o ../../common/configFile/configFile.o   -o longRangeNavigator
```

I do not understand completely the Makefile niether where this action is excecute. 
I just want to add -m32 parameter.

Comment: `LDFLAGS`. But it is easier to just set `CXX = g++ -m32`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `-m32` to the linker too.  One way you can do this by adding this line to your Makefile:

```
LDFLAGS += -m32
```

LDFLAGS is a built-in variable whose value is added to the linker command whenever the linker is invoked by an [implicit rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html#Implicit-Variables)

Comment: i'know that. i just did't know the implicit rules.

Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have yum or apt, you can install gcc 32 , and use it. please use both in or 64 or 32.